# Removing the Option type from a joined RDD

Tags: scala, join, int, rdd

There are two rdds.

```
val pairRDD1 = sc.parallelize(List( ("cat",2), ("girl", 5), ("book", 4),("Tom", 12)))
val pairRDD2 = sc.parallelize(List( ("cat",2), ("cup", 5), ("mouse", 4),("girl", 12)))
```

And then I will do this join operation.

```
val kk = pairRDD1.fullOuterJoin(pairRDD2).collect
```

it shows like that:

```
kk: Array[(String, (Option[Int], Option[Int]))] = Array((book,(Some(4),None)), (Tom,(Some(12),None)), (girl,(Some(5),Some(12))), (mouse,(None,Some(4))), (cup,(None,Some(5))), (cat,(Some(2),Some(2))))
```

if i would like to fill the NONE by 0 and transform `Option[int]` to `Int`.what should I code?Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mapValues` on `kk` as follows (note this is before the `collect`):

```
pairRDD1.fullOuterJoin(pairRDD2).mapValues(pair => (pair._1.getOrElse(0), pair._2.getOrElse(0)))
```

You might have to do this before `collect` in an `RDD`, otherwise you could do:

```
kk.map { case (k, pair) => (k, (pair._1.getOrElse(0), pair._2.getOrElse(0))) }
```

Comment: if pairRDD1 has three elements like that:val pairRDD1 = sc.parallelize(List( ("cat",2,0.1), ("girl", 5,0.3), ("book", 4,0.2),("Tom", 12.0.5)))Thus how should I code?.

Comment: Well then, you can use `._3` to access to the third element and also go with `getOrElse`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on commnets in first answer, if you are fine using DataFrames, you can do with dataframes with any number of columns.

```
val ss = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
    val sc = ss.sparkContext

    import ss.implicits._

    val pairRDD1 = sc.parallelize(List(("cat", 2,9999), ("girl", 5,8888), ("book", 4,9999), ("Tom", 12,6666)))
    val pairRDD2 = sc.parallelize(List(("cat", 2,9999), ("cup", 5,7777), ("mouse", 4,3333), ("girl", 12,1111)))

    val df1 = pairRDD1.toDF
    val df2 = pairRDD2.toDF

    val joined = df1.join(df2, df1.col("_1") === df2.col("_1"),"fullouter")
    joined.show()
```

Here `_1,_2` e.t.c are default column names provided by Spark. But, if you wish to have proper names you can change it as you wish.

Result:

```
+----+----+----+-----+----+----+
|  _1|  _2|  _3|   _1|  _2|  _3|
+----+----+----+-----+----+----+
|girl|   5|8888| girl|  12|1111|
| Tom|  12|6666| null|null|null|
| cat|   2|9999|  cat|   2|9999|
|null|null|null|  cup|   5|7777|
|null|null|null|mouse|   4|3333|
|book|   4|9999| null|null|null|
+----+----+----+-----+----+----+
```